# Ideas for an optimization problem (similar to travelling salesman)

Tags: optimization, algorithms

If you look at the image below. A positive value represents a bucket of sand. A negative number represents a hole that can contain so many buckets.

```
______-3________________-1.5__________|
___2________________________________|
_____________-1____________4_________| 
-2___________________________________|
____________.5_______________________|
_____________1______________________|
```

I want to fill each hole with the available sand. I want to minimize the total distance I need to move carrying a bucket of sand. I would like to be able to solve up to a 1000 piles of sand and holes. A real life example is a farmer grading a paddock. He cuts off the hills and fills in the valleys with his tractor.

Anybody have any suggestions on a good algorithm to solve this ?

Comment: user362723 : this looks similar to the "pick up and delivery problem"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37873/pickup-and-delivery-driver-problem

Comment: As you phrase "to move carrying a bucket of sand", it suggests the maximum capacity to transport sand could be limited to one bucket (at most) on any leg of the travel.  Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, carry is limited to one bucket at a time.